# Error sh: 1: fastqc: not found while calling fastqc

Tags: r, bioinformatics, fastq

I have checked many times that *fastqc* is installed in bin folder and

```
library("fastqcr")
```

is also not giving any error still I am getting error of **sh: 1: fastqc: not found**  for the following command

```
fastqc(fq.dir = "~/WES_Pipeline/Data",   # FASTQ files directory       
       qc.dir = "~/WES_Pipeline/FASTQC", # Results direcory
       threads = 4                       # Number of threads
      )
```

I am not able to figure out what is the possible reason for this error.

I am currently using R-version 3.4.3, Bioconductor 3.6 in ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Does this also return an error: `system("fastqc --version")`?

Comment: @PoGibas: It is also giving the same error. I have started working on bioinformatics few days before. I have developed a pipeline and want to test it. So I have downloaded the data and testing my codes on Linux pc.

Comment: Try with specified path: `system("/PATH1/PATH2/bin/fastqc --version")`

Comment: now it says  `sh: 1: ~/bin/FastQC: Permission denied`  even I always start rstudio from the terminal with the command  `sudo rstudio` .

Comment: Well, it's R and external program permission problem. You should google or look for similar problems on SO.